# Django MEDIA_URL is not serving the file on the local server

Tags: django

I have `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in my `settings.py`.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I am uploading files to

```
uploaded_files = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

I also have defined this in my `url.py`

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the url.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
#     path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.SyncFromQBView.as_view(), name='genplansheet'),
#     path('assemblyItem/detail/<int:pk>', views.AssemblyDetailView.as_view(), name='assembly_detail'),
    path('assemblyItem/edit/<int:pk>', views.AssemblyEditView.as_view(), name='assembly_edit'),
    path('uploadfile/', views.LotFileUploadView.as_view(), name='uploadfile'),
    path('listuploadedfile/', views.LotFilesListView.as_view(), name='listuploadedfile')
]

urlpatterns += [   
    path('genphysicalsheet/', views.PhysicalSheetView.as_view(), name='genphysicalsheet'),
]

# if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The model is

```
class LotFiles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True);
    uploaded_files = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')

    def __str(self):
        return self.name;
```

The view is

```
class LotFilesListView (ListView):
    def get (self, request):
        uploadedFiles = LotFiles.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'genplansheet/filelist.html', {'uploadedFiles' : uploadedFiles})
```

The template is

```
{% block content%}
<h2>Uploaded files</h2>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Upload time</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>download</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for uploadedFile in uploadedFiles %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{uploadedFile.date_of_upload}}</td>
            <td>{{uploadedFile.name}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{uploadedFile.uploaded_files.url}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

The files are getting saved correctly but while accessing them I am getting 404.

Any idea, what might be going wrong here?

Thanks.

Using the URLconf defined in `assemblyautomation.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/ 
genplansheet/ 

^static/(?P<path>.*)$ 
The current path, media/uploads/2019/09/05/1125sft_sold.xlsx, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Are the files being stored in your `/uploads/...` folder? Can you print your `BASE_DIR` in your `settings.py` to check if that's not storing the files in a wrong place? How are you trying to access those files?

Comment: I can't spot any problems with the code you have posted. Please show the full `assemblyautomation.urls`.

Comment: I just updated my question. Please check.

Comment: The files are getting stored correctly at assemblyautomation\media\uploads\2019\09\04

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I had to put

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in the project's url.py and not in the app's url.py